# Using href="/" instead of href="index.html" for start page?

Tags: html, seo

In my language indication for Google down below, I've used href="/" instead of href="index.html". This however seems to give me warnings in webmaster tools. Anyone got any idea of whats going on here?

Webmaster tools tells me this:

- There are Hreflang-tags containing errors.
- Web adress to web page and alternative web page at es-ES does not contain return tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you hreflang you can put your website url

```
 <link rel="alternate" href="http://yourwebsite.com/" hreflang="en" />
```

or

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://yourwebsite.com/index.html" hreflang="en" />
```